# Empty HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I read somewhere that webpages should appear (mostly) intact even with Javascript disabled. In my page, I utilize Javascript to dynamically add a table to my page upon load. I was wondering whether there was any way to display a blank table aside from obnoxious

```
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

placeholder chains such as the above or otherwise hard-coding the default table values into the HTML.

Comment: I dont understand, please clarify more?

Comment: Depending on how it's styled, `<tr><td colspan"5">&nbsp;</td></tr>`?

Comment: create a table inside noscript tag

Comment: I'd say use CSS to style it.

Comment: Why are you filling your `td` elements with `&nbsp;` (I know what they *are*, but why are they *there*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<noscript>` tag runs when javascript was disabled or not there.

```
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

there you can include the table. css can do that job too. set it as hidden by default but if no script, re-write css by setting it to display again, make sure this is below the css responsible for hiding it

here is a link for the non-script tag

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

also you shouldn't worry that much im saying because less than 2% of users are actually browsing with javascript off, and most of those are robots crawling

http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html

```
<noscript>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</noscript>
```